# How can I deploy a Michelson smart contract?

Tags: smart-contracts, michelson, documentation

I'm wondering how to deploy a Michelson smart contract on Tezos.

Maybe I'm just bad at googling, but all the examples I can find are using `liquidity-cli`. I'm not using liquidity for this contract, and would like to learn how to do it without using liquidity. Can't seem to find any docs

Please send halp, links, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the documentation of:

```
tezos-client -A mainnet-node.tzscan.io originate contract
```

It says:

```
tezos-client  originate contract <new> for <mgr> transferring <qty> from <src> running <prg>
```

where `<prg>` is a file containing your Michelson source.

Comment: Is there an easier way with a GUI? (eg. paste code and hit button "deploy")

Answer (score 4):

[ConseilJS beta 0.2.7](https://www.npmjs.com/package/conseiljs/v/0.2.7) has experimental functionality that allows that sort of GUI deployment.

Docs [here](https://cryptonomic.github.io/ConseilJS/#/?id=sendcontractoriginationoperation), code [here](https://github.com/Cryptonomic/ConseilJS/blob/master/src/chain/tezos/TezosNodeWriter.ts#L367).

Answer (score 1):

http://www.liquidity-lang.org/edit/ Also allows to deploy Michelson smart contract. 
You can open "Michelson" tab and paste your Michelson code into text field on right side.